# spring boot caching with caffeine to load entire table in cache with refreshAfterWrite

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, caffeine

I'm already using spring boot and would like to be able to use the the cache layer it provides to cache and entire table in the cache. But I also need to be able to refresh the cache after a period of time (every 5 minutes).

The standard cacheable is easy, but when you try to add refreshAfterWrite, you need to define a loadingCache.

How does one do that (in a spring bean way) when your annotated method doesn't have any parms?

```
@Cacheable("all")
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    ResultSet rset;
    ....
}
```

And what's the point of using the spring abstraction if you now need to define implementation specific objects?

Comment: I don't think it is compatible, as `refreshAfterWrite` requires a `CacheLoader`. Spring instead uses a manual cache with `get(key, func)`. In your case, where there is no cache key, consider instead using Guava's `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration` or have a background thread reset the list instance every period (`volatile ImmutableList<User>`).

Comment: @oggie, @ben-manes, why do you think that you need to add a `loadingCache`? I just tried it & it's working perfectly fine with `refreshAfterWrite`. Spring creates a `BoundedLocalCache` when you define `refreshAfterWrite`. Actually, it just calls `com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.build` method & since `refreshNanos` are not set, `Caffeine` creates a  `BoundedLocalCache` and it just works fine.

Comment: @BenManes is that still async so that the list is updated in the background, and any calls to the method get the old data until the refresh finishes?

Comment: @GokhanOner I was seeing that exception get thrown at startup. The exception thrown stated you need to provide a loadingcache when using refreshafterwrite. Do you have sample code the proves otherwise?

Comment: @Oggie A `Supplier` won't be async. If instead you use an `@Scheduled` task to reload the data and set a volatile field, then it should work. I don't think you need a Spring Cache for your scenario.

Comment: @Oggie, I'm sorry, It seems that I tested with `expireAfterWrite` instead `refreshAfterWrite` and yes, it throws an exception in that case. But since Spring Cache is an abstraction, there is no way Spring can control everything. If the underlying caching solution requires a different cache & cannot build the cache, Spring simply throws return the exception to you. What was your expectation?  And, in this case, why don't you consider using `expireAfterWrite` instead?

Comment: @Oggie, also, as noted here , https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-caffeine, if you define a `CacheLoader<Object, Object>` bean, then  `refreshAfterWrite` also works. Yes, it's a Caffeine specific object but this is how Caffeine works. For other caching solutions in Spring, or for properties other than `refreshAfterWrite` when using Caffeine, it creates the cache successfully.

Comment: @GokhanOner I think the difference between `refreshAfterWrite` and `expireAfterWrite` is that refresh will reload it for me and is non-blocking. But expire means it will delete it from the cache and the next call to the method is blocking while it pulls the data from the DB. I prefer how refresh works.

Comment: also @GokhanOner, like ben-manes said, I don't think you can use CacheLoader when the methods don't have any parms.  I need to load all the data into the cache, so I have no keys.

Comment: @Oggie, I used it in a method with no param & it worked. You may want to try it.

Comment: @GokhanOner thanks. I did as well. It compiles, but the cache isn't being used.  `@Bean
    public LoadingCache<Object, List<User>> cacheLoader() {
        LoadingCache<Object, List<User>> caches = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .refreshAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build(key -> dataSourceService.getAllUsers());
        return caches;
    }`  I think it's still expecting something as a key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166986/discussion-between-oggie-and-gokhan-oner).

Comment: @BenManes I tried out your suggestion of using a volatile field and it seems to be too easy.  `private volatile List<Users> allUsers;` as a class member in the datasource singleton service. And then create a scheduled method in the same class: `@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${cache.refresh.ms:10000}")
    public void userCacheRefresh(){
        this.users = getAllUsers();
    }`

Comment: @Oggie oh.. "it seems to be too easy". Should we try to come up with a more convoluted solution? :-)